# How to add superscript SM to the end of a custom menu name in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, header

So I'm working in a wordpress blog and I need to add a service mark (superscripted letters SM) after one of the menu titles in the header nav bar.

I was going to try and do this via the header CSS, but for some reason when I click on the header.php in theme editor it won't populate in the box. And I don't have record of it elsewhere to just upload a new version.

If I go into the theme via Appearance > Customize > Menus > Primary,
Then I can enter in something new for the navigation label but but I can't make the last two letters superscript.  I already have "red" listed in CSS Classes - is there something else I can put here to tell it to superscript the SM?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.